# array numpy regression linear

Tags: python, numpy, hstack

I have an numpy array that has 3 rows and 3 columns .Like this:

```
100  200  300  
233  699  999 
566  655  895
```

and I want to create a numpy array like this for my linear regression:

```
100  200  300   1
233  699  999   1
566  655  895   1
```

This my code:

```
X=np.hstack((x[:,0]),x[:,1]),x[:,2]) ,np.ones(x.shape[0])))
```

Please how can I edit my code to get my target?

Answer (score 0):

1. You may not break `x` apart in `hstack`
2. You should put the 2-dimension shape in `ones` because the 1-dimension shape arrays are not what you expect.

```py
X = np.hstack((x, np.ones((x.shape[0], 1))))
```